# How to read the temperature of Tesla M2050?

Tags: linux, monitoring, temperature

NVML(nvidia-smi) does not support the temperature for this videocard

nvidia-settings does not work, because it is a cluster node(with 3 gpus) and there is no X

lm-sensors does not show gpus

Ipmitool should do it (found example in google), but for me it shows

```
Temp 16 (GPU2)   | 1Fh | ns  | 11.3 | Disabled
Temp 17 (GPU3)   | 20h | ns  | 11.4 | Disabled
Temp 18 (GPU1)   | 21h | ns  | 11.5 | Disabled
```

is there any other command-line tools or library that can do it?

thank you in advance for any advice

Driver Version: 304.43

Comment: For reviewers: hardware monitoring of components in cluster nodes is *definitely* in the scope of serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the nvidia-debugdump --help' command, I'm a big Tesla user but on Windows not Linux sorry so have no real way to test this but I have a feeling that may help.

Comment: well, probably it contains the temperature in the dump, but

`The "dump" output of nvidia-debugdump is a binary blob that requires internal NVIDIA engineering tools in order to be interpreted.`